# Multiple Command Line Arguments of the same Kind

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

I'm confused as to how to handle multiple command line arguments of the same kind.  I've seen a couple of solutions online, but they do not show what I am looking for:

My command line arguments will be: myar -q test.a 1-s.txt 2-s.txt 3-s.txt 4-s.txt 5-s.txt

so, all of those file names will need to be handled as q inputs.  However, when I try to do this, only the first is taken.  I've tried the below, but it only picks up test.a:

```
opt =  getopt(argc, argv, optString);
while (opt != -1) {
    switch (opt) {

         case 'q':
             globalArgs.filename = optarg;
             break;
```

Is there a way to do this better?  I'm really stuck at the moment.

Comment: Generally that's not the way it works. The option only applies to the next argument. After all the flags are processed, then some arguments are left in argv. After getopt() is done you can "argv += optind" and "argc -= optind" and what's left is in argv. The man page explains this and has an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a variety of options:

- Your example invocation has a single `-q` option followed by a number of file name (non-option) arguments.  You use `q` rather than `q:` as part of the `getopt()` option string, and process the file names as non-option arguments.
- You require users to repeat the `-q` in front of each file name (so `myar -q test.a -q 1-s.txt -q 2-s.txt -q 3-s.txt -q 4-s.txt -q 5-s.txt`).  Inside the option parsing loop, you either process the `optarg` as you encounter it, or you stash the values in a list of some sort for processing later.
- You use `getsubopt()` and require users to list the arguments with comma separators (`myar -q test.a,1-s.txt,2-s.txt,3-s.txt,4-s.txt,5-s.txt`).

The most common technique, and one which would likely be appropriate for an archive program (inference from command name `myar`) is the first: the file names are simply non-option arguments.

Many programs use the second technique.  Consider `cc` with `-l` or `-I` or `-L` options.  Or `make` with `-f` (which specifies another makefile to scan — yes, you can have several `-f` options in a single invocation).

The third technique is more likely to be useful with things other than file names; there's too much risk that file names will contain commas.  It's unlikely that `sort` actually uses `getsubopt()`, but its `-k2n,2` notation is similar.

Comment: so, if I use a switch to differentiate the different options, the getopt goes in the default section?  Or somewhere else

Comment: `getopt()` returns `-1` when it has reached the end of the options.  Anything left over is a non-option argument.  Those are in `argv[optind]` to `argv[argc-1]`.  If you rig the option string correctly with GNU [`getopt()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html) (the first character is `-`), it will return the non-option arguments with a special code (0) and `optarg` set to the value.

Comment: ok, I get it now, thank you.  One thing I have run into is I want to make an array of size (argc-optind) but it won't let me because optind might be undefined.....is there a better way or a way round this, because I'd like these arguments in an array.

Comment: Since `optind` is (or should be) a global variable (declared in `<unistd.h>` under POSIX, or `<getopt.h>` on Linux), there's no question of it being undefined; at worst, it will be zero.  Whether you're using a VLA or doing dynamic allocation with `malloc()` or one of its brethren, it should be clean.

Comment: using POSIX, but I get the warning that it might be defined when I try to do (argc-optind) to set an array size.

Comment: Try this code; it worked OK for me no warnings under stringent compiler options (GCC 4.8.1 on an Ubuntu 12.04 derivative). `#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <getopt.h> /* Linux! */

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int opt;
  while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "f:q")) != -1)
  {
      printf("opt = %d (%c); optind = %d; optarg = <<%s>>\n", opt, opt, optind, optarg);
  }

  char *remainder[argc - optind];
  for (int i = optind; i <= argc; i++)
    remainder[i-optind] = argv[i];
  char **r = remainder;
  while (*r)
    puts(*r++);
  return 0;
}`  _[...continued...]_

Comment: _[...continuation...}_ If that reproduces the warning, specify the compiler options you use. If not, post a minimal version of your code that does reproduce the warning, along with the compiler options, etc.  (I used: `gcc -g -O3 -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Wold-style-declaration -Werror getopt.c -o getopt`.)

Comment: I'm actually going to try to use a linked list to do this, as I think it will work better for the other manipulations I need to do